# Eloquent looks for wrong column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My migration

```
Schema::create('tickets', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('subject');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

    });

    Schema::table('tickets', function($table)
    {
        $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

Relations

```
public function createdTickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ticket');
}


 public function author(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id');
}
```

And store method

```
    public function store(TicketRequest $request)
{
    $ticket = new Ticket($request->all());
    Auth::user()->createdTickets()->save($ticket);

    return redirect('tickets');
}
```

When i try to save a new ticket i recive this error

> QueryException in Connection.php line 624:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table tickets has no column named user_id (SQL: insert into "tickets" ("subject", "body", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at")

Where else i need to specify the FK except the relations?

Comment: Isn't this error saying that you're trying to store data to the `user_id` column in the `Tickets` table, which doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, and it's realy doesn't exsists, but i specified eloquent to use another column $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the desired column name in both of the relation methods.

```
public function createdTickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ticket', 'author_id');
}
```